# Check git repo access rights before performing the clone

Tags: git, makefile

I am using a make file to pull a repo then build. However, the project is also accessible by people who have no access to this repo and should be able to build other parts of the project.

Unfortunately now the build fails for whoever have no access to this specific git repo.

Is there a way I could check if the user has access to the git repo before cloning? This will allow me to skip that part in the make process without killing the build.

Comment: For those of us who don't know git, how would you determine from the command line whether you have access to the repo?

Comment: Depending on your Git server software, it *may* be possible to use that software's APIs to check for permissions (e.g. BitBucket, Github, etc.). But Git itself has no concept of rights or permissions for accessing a remote repository.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solved it for me:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -oBatchMode=yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Git itself doesn't perform access management so there is no built-in way to check access rights other than trying to pull or push.

You have to ignore unsuccessful pull(s) in your makefile(s).